# Is it possible to send a token per request in Spring Security (CSRF Synchronizer Token Pattern)?

Tags: csrf

I have a single page application on Spring. And I want to protect the app from CSRF attacks.

Is it possible to send a token per request in Spring Security (CSRF Synchronizer Token Pattern)?

And does Spring support such feature?

Comment: Because this is about Spring functionality, it would be better asked in StackOVerflow.

Comment: Ok, I need to change the question.